# Package 'android-tools-fsutils' has no installation candidate

Tags: android-sdk-tools, ubuntu-20.04

Trying on install android-tools-fsutils to convert ext4 image to sparse .img format. Error occurred on installation process:

```sh
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package android-tools-fsutils is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  android-sdk-libsparse-utils android-sdk-ext4-utils

E: Package 'android-tools-fsutils' has no installation candidate
```

I tried to install offered libraries and **android-tools-{adb, fastboot}** but it seems didn't able to find ext2simg command for convertion.

I currently work on Ubuntu 20.04 and also add universe repo for software update.
Is there any problems with it on Ubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I find [this link](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/bionic/universe/base/android-tools-fsutils), where you can manually download **.deb** file and install it.

All worked well so far.